# Regex to match a few possible strings with possible leading and/or trailing spaces

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

Let's say I have a string:

> John Smith (auth.), Mary Smith, Richard Smith (eds.), Richie Jack (ed.), Jack Johnny (eds.)

I would like to match:

> John Smith`(auth.),`Mary Smith`,`Richard Smith`(eds.),`Richie Jack`(ed.),`Jack Johnny`(eds.)`

I have came up with a regex but I have a problem with the `|` (or character) because my string contains characters that have to be escaped like `().`. This is what I'm not able deal with. My regex is:

`\s+\((auth\.\)|\(eds\.\))?,\s+`

**EDIT:** I think now that the most universal solution would be to assume that in () could be anything.

Comment: Maybe [`(?:\([^()]*\))?,\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/gM0mX9/1) will be enough?

Comment: will matches will always be encompassed by ( )'s ? also your matches will always be either auth. or eds. ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It won't cach `(eds.)`. In your example there isn't a space between `(auth.),` and other - eds, ed.

Comment: @Veverke My matches won't be always encompassed by (). `Mary Smith, ` could be an example. If there will be (), inside I can find: auth. eds. ed. I think now that the most universal solution would be to assume that in () could be anything.

Comment: Try [`(?:\([^()]*\))?(?:,|$)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/gM0mX9/2) then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It won't catch leading spaces. However, using `\s*(?:\([^()]*\))?(?:,|$)\s*` does. I've added `\s*` before your regex. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: I have not posted my solution because I did not understand what whitespace you need to match. If you need to match any whitespace before and after an optional `(...)` followed with an obligatory `,` or end of string (followed by zero or more whitespace) the one in your comment is what you need.

Comment: It looks like we are close to the solution or have just arrived at it. I would like to match any whitespace before and after an optional (...) but `,` is not obligatory.  The last character could be end of string (followed by zero or more whitespace). If this is the case, please post your solution.

Comment: An obligatory element is either `,` or end of string (`$`) because the non-capturing group `(?:,|$)` has no quantifier. It is not a good idea to make all subpatterns optional, such regexes are very inefficient. I see another solution works for you, please accept it then.

Comment: I marked that answer as solution. But I think your solution is good as well. Please drop me a message if you feel like to discuss it further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\s*\((auth|eds?)?\.\)?,?\s*
```

`\s+` means one or more
`\s*` means zero or more

Based on your comment, I modified the regex:

```
\s*((\([^)]*\))|,)\s*
```

Comment: I have tested your regex on https://regex101.com/r/vI1qI2/1 and it seems that it only matches (auth.).

Comment: Add `/g` in the box next to the regex.

Comment: Great. Works like a charm!